# ComboBox in a Tableview

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am putting together a ComboBox in a QML tableview as follows:

```
TableView {
    id: reviewTable
    frameVisible: false
    sortIndicatorVisible: true
    width: parent.width; height: parent.height
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    TableViewColumn {
        resizable: true
        role: "SeriesDescription"
        title: "Series Description"
        width: 350
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        resizable: false
        role: "TimePoints"
        title: "Time Points"
        width: 100
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "ImageType"
        title: "Image Type"
        width: 100
        delegate: Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            //anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            ComboBox {
                model: ListModel {
                    ListElement {  text: "Veggies" }
                    ListElement {  text: "Fruits" }
                    ListElement {  text: "Cars"  }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this render the combobox in a weird way where the boundaries seeb a bit cut-off. See the attached screenshot. Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here not the perfect solution but anyway... You can change row height by setting `rowDelegate`, for example:

```
rowDelegate: Item {
            height: 30
}
```

and so stretch comboboxes to fill all the space:

```
TableViewColumn {
        role: "ImageType"
        ...
        delegate: Rectangle {
            ComboBox {
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 2
                model: ListModel {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems to solve the problem relatively well. However, there is a new issue when I set the row delegate. When I click on the row, it disappears!

Comment: Ok, so this is simply the row delegate having the default color as white.

Comment: Sure, if you define your own row delegate you have to paint that by yourself.